# Spring boot logbcak to file is not working on tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, logback

I am running spring boot as War on tomcat with logback to console and file.

as long as i run as Java application it is fine i can see logs in console and file.
but i dont see logs printed to file when run on server.

I tried setting logger manager also, didnt work. was wondering to know if some one has faced similar issue.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml" />
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/file-appender.xml" />
    <property name="LOG_FILE" 
     value="${LOG_FILE:-${LOG_PATH:-${LOG_TEMP:-${java.io.tmpdir:-/tmp}}/}app.log}"/>    
    <property name="LOG_FILE_MAX_SIZE" value="10MB" />
    <property name="LOG_TOTAL_SIZE_CAP" value="100MB" />
    <property name="LOG_FILE_MAX_HISTORY" value="20" />
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Do you have a `logback-spring.xml` on the classpath? And have you specified `logging.file=<path to log file>` in `application.properties` or are you setting file path in `logback-spring.xml`?

Comment: yes i have logback-spring.xml on class path. i tried looging.file in application.properties and setting file path in logback-spring.xml as well. but not luck!

Comment: I assume your appender has something like  `<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender"><file>/log/server.log</file>` and your application do have access to write this path?

Comment: yes it does have access to write.

Comment: Can you please share more information like your pom ,yml and logback.xml or logback-spring.xml

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I could fix it by writing the logs to a different folder looks application doesn't have write access the path, however i need to make some changes to springboot main class for loading application props based profile, please find the class below. not sure if others had to the same.

anyway i am glad it is working finally:)

public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

```
public String PROFILE = null;
private static String CONFIG_LOCATION = null;

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    //Grab the active profile from the servlet conext
    PROFILE = servletContext.getInitParameter("spring.profiles.active");
    CONFIG_LOCATION = servletContext.getInitParameter("spring.config.path");        
    super.onStartup(servletContext);
}

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    //...and pass it to the boot application
    application.application().setAdditionalProfiles(PROFILE);
    return application.sources(Application.class).properties(getProperties());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}

//For Loading config from server 
static Properties getProperties() {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("spring.config.location", CONFIG_LOCATION);
    return props;
}
```

}

web.xml

```
<context-param>
 <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
 <param-value>dev</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
 <param-name>spring.config.path</param-name>    
 <param-value>classpath:app.config/</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you have the following dependency :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

or even if you have `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency added, logging should work. 
and have the following in yml or properties file :

```
logging.path=logs
logging.file=${logging.path}/log.log
logging.pattern.file=%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36}.%M - %msg%n
```

and you can also have a `logback.xml` and use the spring default `base.xml` in that so that all default spring configurations apply for your logging as well :

**logback.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>
    <logger name="org.springframework.web" level="DEBUG"/>
</configuration>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. i have the web dependency and i tried with logging properties and logback.xml as you mentioned; both didnt work. i shared the logback-spring.xml which i have

Answer (score 0):

Here is my logback-spring.xml which i have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml" />
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/file-appender.xml" />
    <property name="LOG_FILE" 
     value="${LOG_FILE:-${LOG_PATH:-${LOG_TEMP:-${java.io.tmpdir:-/tmp}}/}app.log}"/>    
    <property name="LOG_FILE_MAX_SIZE" value="10MB" />
    <property name="LOG_TOTAL_SIZE_CAP" value="100MB" />
    <property name="LOG_FILE_MAX_HISTORY" value="20" />
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```